# Actual IP Address not showing in Mongo DB Interaction table though Analytics.RedactIpAddress is set to true

Tags: xdb

I know that by default IP address is hashed in Mongo DB interaction table(**Sitecore 8.1 Update 2)**.

But recently I set the value **Analytics.RedactIpAddress** to true which is by default false, so that instead of saving actual visitor I.P address , it should save 0.0.0.0.
(As described in the link https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/ip-address-hashing.html).

But the issue is that in Mongo DB,  still I.P address is appearing in hashed format instead of 0.0.0.0

Can someone please help me identifying if I am missing something?

Comment: did you try after removing salt value for Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.IpHashProvider setting? by default, all contact IP addresses are hashed when they are saved to the xDB database.

Comment: Yes, I removed the salt value, still actual value is not appearing.

Comment: How are new interactions recorded?  redacted or still hashed?